# Sinatra + Rack routing

Tags: sinatra, rack, cherokee, respond-to

I have an app file that looks like this ws_app.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/respond_to'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-timestamps'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

load 'models/Battery.rb'

Sinatra::Application.register Sinatra::RespondTo
DataMapper::setup(:default,"sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/mpt_hmi.sqlite3")

class MPTHMI  < Sinatra::Base

    load 'controller/BatteryController.rb'

end
```

The modules/Battery.rb looks like this:

```
class Battery
   include DataMapper::Resource

   property :id, Serial
   property :i_battery_manager_id, Integer
   property :c_battery_number, String
   property :c_battery_state, String
   property :c_voltage_byte, String
   property :i_voltage_int, Integer
   property :i_temperature, Integer
   property :i_resistance, Integer
   property :i_capacity, Integer
   property :i_cell_balancing_duration, Integer
   property :i_total_cell_balancing_duration, Integer
   property :i_age, Integer
   property :i_time_to_service, Integer
   property :created_at, DateTime
   property :updated_at, DateTime

   def to_my_json
     {
      :i_battery_manager_id => self.i_battery_manager_id,
      :c_battery_number => self.c_battery_number,
      :c_battery_state => self.c_battery_state,
      :c_voltage_byte => self.c_voltage_byte,
      :i_voltage_int => self.i_voltage_int,
      :i_temperature => self.i_temperature,
      :i_resistance => self.i_resistance,
      :i_capacity => self.i_capacity,
      :i_cell_balancing_duration => self.i_cell_balancing_duration,
      :i_total_cell_balancing_duration => self.i_total_cell_balancing_duration,
      :i_age => self.i_age,
      :i_time_to_service => self.i_time_to_service
     }
  end

end
```

The controller/BatteryController.rb file looks like this:

```
get '/battery/:id' do 
   @battery = Battery.get(params[:id])
   respond_to do |wants|
     wants.html { erb :battery } # html
     wants.json { @battery.to_my_json.to_s } # json
   end
end

get '/batteries' do 
  @batteries = Battery.all
  respond_to do |wants|
    wants.html { erb :batteries } # html
    wants.json { 
      @batteries.all.inject({}) { |hsh, obj| 
        hsh[obj.id] = obj.to_my_json
        hsh
      }.to_json
    } 
  end
end
```

This works perfectly when I run Sinatra normally, like so:

```
$ ruby ws_app.rb
== Sinatra/1.3.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

Then go here:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4567/battery/5.json
```

I get the JSON I'm expecting:

```
{:i_battery_manager_id=>1, :c_battery_number=>"5", :c_battery_state=>"3", :c_voltage_byte=>"145", :i_voltage_int=>191, :i_temperature=>107, :i_resistance=>81, :i_capacity=>228, :i_cell_balancing_duration=>127, :i_total_cell_balancing_duration=>37, :i_age=>111, :i_time_to_service=>211}
```

but I need to deploy this on a Cherokee web server, so I want to make a rack config.ru file for this...

So I have a file mpthmiws.rb which contains

```
load 'ws_app.rb'

MPTHMI.run
```

And a config.ru file which contains

```
load 'mpthmiws.rb'

run MPTHMI.new
```

When I run

```
$ rackup config.ru 
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

and go here:

```
http://0.0.0.0:9292/battery/1.json
```

but then I get the famous, "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty - try get '/battery/1.json' do "Hello World" end

If I take the first route from the controller/BatteryController.rb file and put it inside HMIMPT class in the ws_app.rb file like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/respond_to'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-timestamps'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

load 'models/Battery.rb'

Sinatra::Application.register Sinatra::RespondTo
DataMapper::setup(:default,"sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/mpt_hmi.sqlite3")

class MPTHMI  < Sinatra::Base

   get '/battery/:id' do 
     @battery = Battery.get(params[:id])
     respond_to do |wants|
       wants.html { erb :battery } # html
       wants.json { @battery.to_my_json.to_s } # json
     end
  end

end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `respond_to' for #<MPTHMI:0x00000001240a80>
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that thing with mpthmiws.rb and config.ru is overly complicated. Delete mpthmiws.rb and use this config.ru for use with `rackup config.ru`:

```
require './ws_app'

run MPTHMI
```

If you want to run the App with plain old `ruby ws_app.rb`, use this run.rb file:

```
require './ws_app'

MPTHMI.run!
```

Which brings us to the next point: NEVER EVER USE `load`! It executes the code in the loaded file, but it does not bring over any defined variables, functions etc. Use `require` instead! Here you must prefix the path with `./` or add `./` to `$LOAD_PATH`, but in turn you can omit the `.rb` extension.

Next is your BatteryController.rb file. It should look like this:
require 'sinatra/respond_to'

```
class BatteryController < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::RespondTo

  get '/battery/:id' do 
     # ...
  end

  get '/batteries' do 
    # ...
  end
end
```

And this is also the point where you `register` your extensions — in the class where you need it.

Now that we understand how `load` works, you may already have noticed that you were not actually loading the `get` blocks into the `MPTHMI` class, but rather executing them outside of the class. That is the only reason why your app worked anyway with plain old `ruby ws_app.rb`!

You can properly include your controller into a class with `use`:

```
# require all your gems
# ...

require './models/Battery'
require './controller/BatteryController'

DataMapper::setup(:default,"sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/mpt_hmi.sqlite3")

class MPTHMI < Sinatra::Base
    use BatteryController
end
```

You can also leave off the `register` in here. Feel free to comment if you have further questions!

---

And here's the full diff:

```
diff --git a/config.ru b/config.ru
index eaa15fe..1568544 100644
--- a/config.ru
+++ b/config.ru
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-load 'mpthmiws.rb'
+require './ws_app'

-run MPTHMI.new
+run MPTHMI
diff --git a/controller/BatteryController.rb b/controller/BatteryController.rb
index 31e4910..c500c48 100644
--- a/controller/BatteryController.rb
+++ b/controller/BatteryController.rb
@@ -1,20 +1,27 @@
-get '/battery/:id' do 
-   @battery = Battery.get(params[:id])
-   respond_to do |wants|
-     wants.html { erb :battery } # html
-     wants.json { @battery.to_my_json.to_s } # json
-   end
-end
+require 'sinatra/respond_to'

-get '/batteries' do 
-  @batteries = Battery.all
-  respond_to do |wants|
-    wants.html { erb :batteries } # html
-    wants.json { 
-      @batteries.all.inject({}) { |hsh, obj| 
-        hsh[obj.id] = obj.to_my_json
-        hsh
-      }.to_json
-    } 
+class BatteryController < Sinatra::Base
+  register Sinatra::RespondTo
+  
+  get '/battery/:id' do 
+     @battery = Battery.get(params[:id])
+     respond_to do |wants|
+       wants.html { erb :battery } # html
+       wants.json { @battery.to_my_json.to_s } # json
+     end
   end
-end
+
+  get '/batteries' do 
+    @batteries = Battery.all
+    respond_to do |wants|
+      wants.html { erb :batteries } # html
+      wants.json { 
+        @batteries.all.inject({}) { |hsh, obj| 
+          hsh[obj.id] = obj.to_my_json
+          hsh
+        }.to_json
+      } 
+    end
+  end
+
+end
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/mpt_hmi.sqlite3 b/mpt_hmi.sqlite3
index e69de29..9897cd9 100644
Binary files a/mpt_hmi.sqlite3 and b/mpt_hmi.sqlite3 differ
diff --git a/mpthmiws.rb b/mpthmiws.rb
deleted file mode 100644
index 87f3406..0000000
--- a/mpthmiws.rb
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,3 +0,0 @@
-load 'ws_app.rb'
-
-MPTHMI.run
diff --git a/ws_app.rb b/ws_app.rb
index 1cab867..4a6e332 100644
--- a/ws_app.rb
+++ b/ws_app.rb
@@ -1,19 +1,18 @@
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'sinatra'
-require 'sinatra/respond_to'
 require 'dm-core'
 require 'dm-migrations'
 require 'dm-timestamps'
 require 'json'
 require 'csv'

-load 'models/Battery.rb'
+require './models/Battery'
+require './controller/BatteryController'

-Sinatra::Application.register Sinatra::RespondTo
 DataMapper::setup(:default,"sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/mpt_hmi.sqlite3")

 class MPTHMI  < Sinatra::Base
-
-    load 'controller/BatteryController.rb'
+    
+    use BatteryController

 end
```

Comment: Thanks padde, you changes worked. The JSON views still work but the html views do not. Sinatra responds with can't find batteries.html.erb. I've placed this file in a directory called views which worked fine before I made the changes. Any thoughts? Thanks